# XCode 7.3 Not showing "general" tab in options.

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to access the "general" tab of the Xcode options for a target I'm trying to build but there seems to be none. 
Heres an image of my settings tab with the target selected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYcx7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try this.[General option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiqoK.png)
Click the left top corner icon (Hide project and targets list button) that appears in the image and then a list will show you your project, then click your project and the general option now appear.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiqoK.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project was not created correctly for iOS. You need to do File->New->Project. Then, go to iOS category and choose your project type (usually single view application). Then input your project name, preferred language, organization, etc. and create the project. Now, when you click on the target, you will see the general tab.

Comment: I don't want to build for just iOS though. I built the project as a command line project because I want to test out some Swift code.

Comment: Building for iOS gives you the choice of using Swift code if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

that message is talking about your IOS device general tab so you have to go to your (iphone or ipad) setting -> general -> (in IOS 11)Profile & Device Management -> Then select your apple Id which is signed in xcode 
**Note: your ios device should connected to internet**